# can we remove `""` entries from an ArrayList objects in one shot?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Just out of curiosity- Is there any way to remove `""` entries from an ArrayList object which has been assigned the values using the range?

```
  Dim ArrListChildDetails : Set ArrListChildDetails = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

  ArrListChildDetails = Range("A4:E6") 'Is it possible?
  And If empty Strings("") there,can we remove it in one shot?
```

Please guide here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [ArrayList Reference From MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)

- `ArrListChildDetails.Clear` : Removes all the elements in the `ArrayList`
- `Remove` :Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the ArrayList.
- `RemoveAt` :Removes the element at the specified index of the ArrayList.

**Choose objects, knowing what they can do, and if they have the properties that you need.**